# Best method of Error Correction in Quantum Key Distribution

Tags: cr.crypto-security, quantum-computing, quantum-information

As far as I can tell, almost all implementations of QKD use [Brassard and Salvail's CASCADE algorithm](http://assassin.cs.rpi.edu/~edmanm2/wiphysec/cache/brassard%3aeurocrypt94.ps) for error correction. Is this really the best known method of correcting errors in a shared sequence of random qubits, or is there a better proposition that implementations of QKD should be using instead?

Comment: Nice question. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, there is a lot going on in the research of better and faster error correction codes for QKD. The biggest bottleneck of the CASCADE protocol is that it requires a lot of classical communication between Alice and Bob.

A lot of work has been done on LDPC codes. You can have a look to the following papers:

-[Efficient reconciliation protocol for discrete-variable quantum key distribution](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2140) (arXiv:0901.2140v1)

-[Rate Compatible Protocol for Information Reconciliation: An application to QKD](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2660) (arXiv:1006.2660v1).

Moreover, I suggest to look at the slides at https://sqt.ait.ac.at/software/projects/hipanq/wiki/Schedule where there are many talks about error correction in QKD.

Finally, regarding the applications, I would like to point out that the [demostration that has been done in Tokyo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3566) was also implemented using LDPC codes (see arXiv:1103.3566v1 on page 13 for a reference).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a list of publications about error correction (information reconciliation) for QKD: http://gcc.ls.fi.upm.es/en/publications.html

Performance using standardized low-density parity-check codes was recently published in the following work: Key Reconciliation for High Performance Quantum Key Distribution, Scientific Reports 3, Article number: 1576

Some figures with efficiencies and parity-check matrices are also available at http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/jmartinez/qkd_error_correction.html